# Python: push file to Android device pass but the file is empty

Tags: android, python, appium, driver

I have application that i am testing and i want to push `file` into my `android` device (real device)

This is what i have try:

```
self.driver.push_file('/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/photo.png', r'C:\photo.png')
```

So this operation is pass and i can see the `file` on my `device` but its `size` is `1kb` and when i try to open it i have this `message`:

> Its looks like we dont support this file format

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: what api/sdk do you use?

Comment: How can i check it ?

Comment: I mean library/modules from python you use

Comment: i am using python 3.7 and newest selenium

Comment: are you using [this](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/files/push-file/)?

Comment: This command: driver.push_file('/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/photo.png', r'C:\photo.png')

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that using **Appium** with the **Python** language, when you call the [self.driver.push_file()](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/push-file) method, the second parameter is the *Contents of file in base64* (and not the path of the file on your machine).

That means that you first have to read the file, convert it to base64 (and decode it using utf-8) and only then pass it to this method:

```
import base64
...
with open(r'C:\photo.png','rb') as file:
    driver.push_file('/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/photo.png',
                     base64.b64encode(file.read()).decode('utf-8'))
```

Alternatively, you can simply use the following command (adding just `source_path=` to your snippet):

```
self.driver.push_file('/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/photo.png', source_path=r'C:\photo.png')
```

..since the push_file() method was recently updated to support also source path (see [Pull #270](https://github.com/appium/python-client/pull/270)):

```
def push_file(self, destination_path, base64data=None, source_path=None)
```

I would recommend on the `source_path` parameter of course :)